# Set Content-Type header in do_parse_request filter

Tags: plugins, headers

I have a plugin that sends binary content inside a do_parse_request filter and I need to set the proper Content-Type header but when I do it I got an error saying that Headers was already sent.

How can I prevent wordpress from sending headers until my plugin have done it's work?

Comment: WordPress doesn't send its headers that early, you probably have something else unintentionally sending output to the browser. Check for spaces before php tags or anything else that might be generating output.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `do_parse_request` in the **plugins_loaded** action hook.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', setup_parse_request' );

function setup_parse_request() {
    // handle parse request
}
```